# What is causing a "SIGABRT" error in the AppDelegate file in Xcode 8.3?

Tags: swift3, sigabrt, xcode8

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {// Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

```
var window: UIWindow?
```

"Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" is at the end of the "class" line.

SUMMARY
The user enters the meal sub-total, tip percent, and tax percent; and the program outputs tax amount, tip amount, and total cost of meal. It is a simple one-view program. I made no changes to the AppDelegate file. All code was added to the ViewController file.

There are no other errors in the AppDelegate file. There are several warnings in the ViewController file but no errors. On running, the simulator (iPhone 7) displays but is empty. CONSOLE OUTPUT is after the code for ViewController.

Code for ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var txtMealCost: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var txtTipPercent: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var txtTaxRatePercent: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTaxAmt: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTipAmt: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTotalCost: UILabel!

/*    var mealCost = Double(txtMealCost.text)
    var tipPercent : Float = 0
    var taxRatePercent : Float = txtTaxRatePercent.text
    var taxAmt : Float = 0
    var tipAmt : Float = 0
    var totalCost : Float = 0
    var totalCost = mealCost + taxAmt + tipAmt
*/
    @IBAction func btnCalculate(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var mealCost = Double(txtMealCost.text!)!
        var tipPercent = Double(txtTipPercent.text!)!
        var taxRatePercent = Double(txtTaxRatePercent.text!)!
        var taxAmt = mealCost * taxRatePercent
        var lblTaxAmt = String(taxAmt)
        var tipAmt = mealCost * tipPercent
        var lblTipAmt = String(lblTipAmt)
        var totalCost = mealCost + taxAmt + tipAmt
        var lblTotalCost = String(totalCost)

/*        var fMealCost = (mealCost as NSString).floatValue
        var fTipPercent = tipPercent
        var fTaxRatePercent = taxRatePercent
        var fTaxAmt = taxAmt
        var fTipAmt = tipAmt
*/   //     var fTotalCost = totalCost
        }
    @IBAction func Clear(_ sender: UIButton) {
    txtMealCost.text = ""
    txtTipPercent.text = ""
    txtTaxRatePercent.text = ""
    lblTaxAmt.text = ""
    lblTipAmt.text = ""
    lblTotalCost.text = ""
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }
}
```

CONSOLE OUTPUT:
2017-04-19 14:10:54.720 MealCostCalculator[1932:96055] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key MealCost.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ccf4b0b **exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a085141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ccf4a59 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000109b9ae8b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 292
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010a6f2644 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 87
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010a95f6b9 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc9ae8d -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 269
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010a95e06f -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1856
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010a6f8c73 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010a6f9589 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010a6f98ba -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 195
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010a6fa10a -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010a5c263a -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 65
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010a5c2d20 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 294
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010a5d5b6e -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010a54f31f -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4346
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010a555584 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1709
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010a552793 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 182
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010e4045f6 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 24
    19  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010e40446d -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 186
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010e4047f6 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc9ac01 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc800cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc7f5ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc7f016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010a55102f -[UIApplication _run] + 468
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010a5570d4 UIApplicationMain + 159
    27  MealCostCalculator                  0x0000000109aa9487 main + 55
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010dc9465d start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)`enter code here`

Comment: Check your storyboard for an outlet called "MealCost".  Maybe it should be "txtMealCost".

Comment: Never mind ALL. I found the errors and program runs now.